# Replace string in file with string from other file, once per string in other file

Tags: linux, shell

I have two files. One of them is a letter file that has the word `NAME` in it and I want to replace it with the content of the other file. The other file contains a list of names.

For example, the letter file is

```
 Thanks NAME, bye NAME
```

and the list of names in the file name is

```
Mark
Micheal
Jon
...
```

and  I want the original letter file with no change, I want to generate copies of the original letter with the change ,for example letter1 contain `Thanks Mark, bye Mark` and `letter2 Thanks Micheal, bye Micheal` and so on.

How can I do that using Linux shell script?
this is my code

```
for (( i=1 ; i<= cat names | wc -l ; i++ ))

do

sed 's/NAME/names/g' letter.txt > letter1.txt

done
```

the `cat names | wc -l` didn't work  and  `sed 's/NAME/names/g' letter.txt > letter1.txt` replace the word `NAME` with `names`and not the content of the file names. Also I don't know how to create many copies of letter file.

Comment: Currently, this is just a requirement of what you want. A better question would a) be more specific (for example, should the output go to a different file each?) and b) show your own efforts and where you failed.

Comment: Also, it's probably "Michael".

Comment: yes, I want the original letter file with on change, I want to generate copies of the original letter with the change ,for example letter1 contain "Thanks Mark, bye Mark" and letter2 "Thanks Micheal, bye Micheal".

Comment: You might want to [edit] the question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Benjamin W. I edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the name as an addition to the filename as well.

So in the loop read each the name into a variable, and use that for the replacement.

```
cat names | while read -r name; do
   sed 's/NAME/'"$name"'/g' letter.txt > letter."$name".txt
done
```

This will than create files named `letter.Mark.txt`, `letter.Michael.txt` a.s.o.

If you have to have files according to the known number in `$i`, inside your loop assign the variable with:

```
name="$(cat names|head -n "$i"|tail -n1)"
```

(might be a little slow but it works)

Comment: if I put the second solution inside the for loop, as I said before  `cat names | wc -l` didn't work. how I make it works?

Comment: `$( cat names | wc -l )` but i would not recommend that, use the first solution and a counter `i=$(( i + 1 ))` instead.

Comment: I am very grateful to you for your help.